# Django How can I initial the object ID of all objects in queryset in a formset hidden field?

Tags: django

I'm trying to create a simple inbox application that allow users to send each other message using the UserModel.

How can I populate id of all objects in a queryset in a hidden field of a formset? Because when I try

```
File "C:\mysite\pet\views.py" in message
 913.     initial.update({'hidden_field': messages.id})
```

Exception Type: AttributeError at /message/
    Exception Value: 'function' object has no attribute 'id'

```
class Message(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='sender')
    recipient = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='recipient')
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    body = models.CharField(max_length=1000)
    read = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    trash = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    sentmessage = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    thread = models.ForeignKey(Thread,blank=True,null=True)
    draft = models.BooleanField(default=False)


    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.body
```

views

```
@login_required
def message(request):    
    person = Person.objects.get(user=request.user)
    messages = Message.objects.filter(recipient=request.user.id).order_by("-created").values    
    initial = {}
    initial.update({'hidden_field': messages.id})

    form = formset_factory(CheckBoxForm)
    formset = form(initial=initial)
    return render(request,'messages.html',{'messages':messages,'form':form,'person':person})
```

forms

```
class CheckBoxForm(forms.Form):
    checkbox = forms.BooleanField(required=False)
    hidden_field = forms.CharField(widget=forms.HiddenInput())
```

template

```
     {% for m in messages %}
    {{m.body}}
   {% endfor %}
```

@ new code

```
 @login_required
 def message(request):    
     messages = Message.objects.filter(recipient=request.user).order_by("-created")  

     form = CheckBoxForm()
     if request.method =='POST':
         form = ReplyForm(request.POST)
         if form.is_valid():
             id = request.POST.get('hidden_field', False)
             Message.objects.filter(pk=id).delete()
     return render(request,'messages.html',     {'messages':messages,'form':form,'person':person})
```

Comment: You can only access the id in an instance of the model class. I assume you are putting the checkbox next to your messages, although it is not there in you code.  If this is the case, why not just put <input type="hidden" value={{m.id}}> in your template?

Comment: @lntheNoob I posted some new code above , I did that . For instance if I have 5 checkbox . and try to delete it via post . It only delete one

Comment: @IntheNoob if their were many messages then their many checkbox . How would you create a function that would delete the objects?

Answer (score 1):

To be honest, I would do this with javascript.  Maybe this is not considered the best way, or actually the best way, but nonetheless it is a way.

Template:

```
<head> 
<script>
checkbox=getelementbyId('#container');
var itemlist= [];
function togglelist(newitem){
    field=getelementbyId('#'+newitem);
if (!field.value){
        itemlist.push(newitem)
}
else{
   itemlist.remove(itemlist.indexOf(newitem))
};
checkbox.innerHTML="<input type='hidden' id='checkbox' label='hidden_field' value='"+String(itemlist)+"'>";

}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="container"> </div>
{% for m in messages %}
<input type="checkbox" id="{{m.id}}" onchange="togglelist({{m.id}})">
{{m.body}}
{% endfor %}
```

Your models.py you can get rid of the boolean value and just have one character field, hidden_field.
Then in your views.py just parse the list from the string, using ast library:

```
import ast
form = CheckBoxForm()
 if request.method =='POST' and form.is_valid():
         deletelist = request.POST.get('hidden_field', False)
         ids=ast.literal_eval(deletelist)
         for id in ids:
             Message.objects.filter(pk=id).delete()
```

Sorry I wasn't able to test this, but I hope it is helpful.

Comment: thank you for helping me , I get this error 'int' object is not iterable pointing to for id in ids: . what should I do?

Comment: when you print out the variable, ids, what does it show?  Should be a list and not an int, if this code words.  Deletelist should be a string that looks like a list, which are notated the same in JS and python so it should work

Comment: Did you put my code into your template? I suspect not.  The javascript creates a list of id's in a string form that python can interpret.

Comment: Do i need to have a js file?

Comment: Sorry, I recognized an error in my code, which I fixed.  Basically, the javascript generates a string according to changes in the checkbox, and sends it to the 'container' div.  It is slightly convoluted and would probably take a bit of fiddling.  It should work, however.

Comment: ok , I tried again . It doesn't seem to work thank you for helping me

Comment: am I suppose to see the string in the container div? because it doesn't show anything inside the div